# How to stop insert in a transaction in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Create query using `BEGIN TRAN` statement to insert two rows within `BEGIN TRY` if transaction count is greater than 1, catch error and rollback the transaction, otherwise print “transaction committed” (this is my teacher question the idea is that it should not insert more than 1 row by using the `@@trancount` is greater than one the transaction is rolled back)

This is the code that I wrote

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN;

        INSERT INTO [Info].[Country]([name]) VALUES ('Italy');
        PRINT @@TRANCOUNT

        BEGIN TRAN
            INSERT INTO [Info].[Country]([name]) VALUES ('Jorden');
            PRINT @@TRANCOUNT

            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 1
                PRINT 'Rollback the transaction...';
            ELSE 
                PRINT 'transaction succeeded';
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH;
```

It keeps inserting the two rows even though the trans count is greater than 1

How can I fix this?!!

This is the result

[image: my result]

Comment: It has 2 inserts, therefore it must insert two rows. The check for trancount only prints a message, it doesn't do anything else beyond that.

Comment: The value returned by @@TRANCOUNT has no relationship to the number of rows inserted by one (or more) statements. Perhaps your teacher mentioned @@ROWCOUNT? And your logic is faulty. In your IF statement, you only print the message requested - you do not rollback. You will need a being/end block for the THEN portion of your IF statement to execute both print and rollback.

Comment: Notice also that your teacher requested "transaction committed" - what does your code print? Writing code requires that you pay attention to details.

Comment: @SMor i did pay attention to this. and i am going to change this at the end. i uploaded the result it gives me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you're looking for using `@@ROWCOUNT` instead of `@@TRANCOUNT`

```
BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRAN MyTran;
    INSERT INTO Countries(Name) VALUES 
    ('Italy'),
    ('Jorden');
    IF @@ROWCOUNT > 1 
      ROLLBACK TRAN MyTran;
        ELSE
          COMMIT TRAN MyTran;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  RAISERROR ('Error Message',  
             16, -- Severity.  
             1 -- State.  
             ); 
  ROLLBACK TRAN MyTran;
END CATCH;
```

If you really want to use nested transactions and use `@@TRANCOUNT`

```
BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRAN MyTran;
    INSERT INTO Countries(Name) VALUES ('Italy');
      BEGIN TRAN MySecTran;
        INSERT INTO Countries(Name) VALUES ('Jorden');
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 1 
          ROLLBACK TRAN;
            ELSE
              COMMIT TRAN;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    RAISERROR ('Error Message', 
               16, -- Severity.  
               1 -- State.  
               );
    ROLLBACK TRAN;
END CATCH;
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4645e782684921d1354238768afdd6e8) where you can un-comment one of the two and see how it's working.

---

Update:

> i checked it again. it did not insert any row in the table. but it should insert the first one

Then you need to save the tran as

```
BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRAN MyTran;
    INSERT INTO Countries(Name) VALUES ('Italy');
    SAVE TRAN MySaveTran; 
  BEGIN TRAN MySecTran;
    INSERT INTO Countries(Name) VALUES ('Jorden');
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 1 
      ROLLBACK TRAN MySaveTran;
  COMMIT TRAN;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  RAISERROR ('Error Message', 
             16, -- Severity.  
             1 -- State.  
             );
  ROLLBACK TRAN;
END CATCH;
```

Comment: it still inserts the two rows. it should not insert the second row because the transcount will be greater than 1

Comment: i did tested it. the result was two rows affected. it inserted the data.

Comment: i checked it again. it did not insert any row in the table. but it should insert the first one

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN;
INSERT INTO [Info].[Country]([name]) VALUES ('Italy');
print @@TRANCOUNT
Begin tran
INSERT INTO [Info].[Country]([name]) VALUES ('Jorden');
print @@TRANCOUNT
if @@TRANCOUNT>1

PRINT 'Rollback the transaction...';
else 
print 'transaction successes';
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH;
GO
```

You are not actually doing a rollback, you're just printing 'Rollback the transaction' change to

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN;
INSERT INTO [Info].[Country]([name]) VALUES ('Italy');
print @@TRANCOUNT
Begin tran
INSERT INTO [Info].[Country]([name]) VALUES ('Jorden');
print @@TRANCOUNT
if @@TRANCOUNT>1
 begin
  PRINT 'Rollback the transaction...';
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
 end
else 
print 'transaction successes';
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH;
GO
```

Comment: it still insert the two rows. it should only insert the first one. and raise error at the second one because the transcount became more than 1. i hope you understood what i mean :)

Answer (score 0):

besides the other mentioned mistakes. I think your teacher wants you to make proper use of the try catch pattern. For this you need to know that the CATCH block is only executed when an error occurs inside of the try block.
See [TRY...CATCH (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

You can raise an error using the THROW statement 
[THROW (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```sql
IF @@ROWCOUNT > 1
 THROW 51000, 'row count greater 1.', 1;
```